# Scene takes 3-4 seconds to be presented. SKScene SKView

Tags: ios, swift, skscene, skview

From the main menu scene, pressing play to take you to the game happens instantly. However to go from the game back to the main menu scene, takes around 3 to 4 seconds from the moment the user presses the exit button. Is there any reason for this? The main menu screen just has 3 SKSpriteNodes, so nothing overly complex.

Is this something I would need to use background threading in order to fix?

I am presenting the scene like so:

```
        //Pressed exit button
        if CGRectContainsPoint(exitButton.frame, location) 

            //Present main menu scene
            let skView = self.view! as SKView
            var scene: TitleScene!
            scene = TitleScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

Comment: Profile your app in instruments to see which is the time consuming task... Are you preloading assets or something in your titleScene?

Comment: Are you doing your texture/assets loading in the `init` or `didMovetoView` functions in `TitleScene`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am loading everything in `didMoveToView`

Comment: ok. so that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you! So should I be loading them in init then? I wonder why the init method is not given by default when the file is created.

Comment: nope, not init, same problem. add a loading scene on startup just before main scene